# Bootstrap styles not applying to angular component

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to apply the bootstrap 5.3.0 style to navigation bar according to the tutorial but the result looks default (differs from the tutorial).

The component HTML is

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li> <a href="#">Recipes</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Shopping List</a> </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Save Data</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li> <a href="#">Save Data</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Fetch Data</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Bootstrap was added to angular.json file

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
        ]
```

Angular:

```
Angular: 16.1.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
@angular-devkit/core            16.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.1.4
@angular/cli                    16.1.4
@schematics/angular             16.1.4
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking at an old tutorial, for a different version of bootstrap.

Bootstrap 5 does not use `navbar-default` or `navbar-header`. So change `navbar-default` to just `navbar`.

You do not need the `show` class where you have `navbar-collapse` for the collapse to work, so it can be removed.

You also need to add the `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` attribute to the dropdown toggle link `<a>` tag and set the `data-bs-target` attribute to the ID of the dropdown menu.

It might look something like this:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a href="#" class="nav-link">Recipes</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a href="#" class="nav-link">Shopping List</a> </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Save Data</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Save Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Fetch Data</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```